# Why is a period being misplaced in my HTML?

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

I have an HTML email that is inserting a period at certain breakpoints in my text, even though it's not in the code.

At this breakpoint, it's fine:

[image: Here, the text is fine.]

At this breakpoint, there is a period inserted at the beginning of the third line of copy.

[image: At this breakpoint, there is a random period inserted at the beginning of the third line of copy.]

I can't see anything that would cause this in the code.

```
<!-- BODY COPY -->
<tr>
    <td class="fluid-td darkmode-text fallback-font" width="100%" align="left" style="Margin:0 auto;padding:0 30px 0 30px;font-family:'Roboto',Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 25px; color: #333333;">
        <div class="darkmode-text fallback-font" style="Margin: 0; padding: 0; font-family:'Roboto',Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 15px; line-height: 25px; color: #333333;">
            <p style="Margin:0;padding:0;">Take on tightly-curved surfaces with extra-pliable ID. Sticks to stainless steel and Polypropylene.</p>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: ...why are you using `<table>` for layout? Unless you're specifically targeting Desktop Office Outlook it's just going to cause you headaches...

Comment: I'd guess a text direction rule somewhere causing the problem.

Comment: If you can open the HTML email in a browser like Firefox or Chrome, you can inspect that part to see the actual CSS codes being applied.

Comment: @Dai for E-Mails, you still have to do it this way, if you want to have any chance of cross-client-compatibility

Comment: Can you post some of your css? Specifically; the classes `fluid-td` `darkmode-text`, and `fallback-font` ?

Comment: That's not what "random" means. It's obviously there for a reason. Please provide your CSS and any other relevant information so we can answer.  And it _is_ in your code. It's the period from the end of the second sentence, just out of position.

Comment: No such thing `align="left"` Plus other invalid, inline CSS entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a rtl-ltr-issue. The period is not "new", it's left when it should be right.

Try to add the attribute `dir="ltr"` to the containing element.

Comment: Why wouldn't the rest of the text be reversed?

Comment: because other css

Comment: Adding this to the paragraph tag worked! I wasn't aware of the dir attribute. Thank you so much!